# Java I want to hold a variable and i have 2 applets

Tags: java, object, applet

So what is my problem:

I have 2 .bat-files which I run seperately. The first one will create an Object with a property.
When I run the second one, this will need to call the object from te first applet...

How can I do this?

for example: I make in the first applet a Dog-object and I want to call that Dog-object from my second applet.

Comment: Applets are embedded in web pages, not run from the command line.  So do you have applets, or not?

Comment: the class extends Applet

Comment: 1) Do you intend to embed these applets in a web page?  2) Why are you running them using .bat files?

Comment: No, no web page.. It's just for testing between connections.. I just want to know iff it's possible to call the Object from the first applet to the other. for example: with sessions, threads,...? fyi: The first .bat file is still running at the moment i start the second one

Comment: If there is no need to embed the GUI in a web page, **don't - use - applets!**  Applets vastly complicate the task you are trying to achieve, since they operate within a security sand-box that restricts many of the ways a programmer would normally use to communicate between apps.

Comment: I have no choice, it's a simulation for a client-server application.

Comment: That does not make any sense whatsoever.  A client-server app. does not have to be based on applets.  It could be using frames, or use the command line (without any GUI).  What *exactly* is the specification that you have to implement (word for word)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways for 2 apps. to communicate.  But focusing on a couple that are good for Java objects.

1. [Sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).  This depends on both apps. being run at the same time.
2. [Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).  Store the `Object` to disk in the first app., then the second app. can read it from disk when needed.

As for how to serialize/deserialize the `Object`, you might look to using either:

1. [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) / [`ObjectInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html)
2. [`XMLEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) / [`XMLDecoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLDecoder.html)

Comment: that was my idea also (the files), glad you confirmed it

Answer (score 1):

First let me fix your question. You are using term "applet" that confused some people. You really mean "application".

So, your question is how to send object from one application to another. There are a lot of ways. For example you can use built-in java serialization mechanism. In this case the class you are instantiating must implement `Serializable` interface. If the first application is still alive when second starts you can use socket to pass this serialized object. If not, the first app can store serialized object in file and the second will read it later.

Comment: *"You really mean "application"."*  The OP stated in a comment *"the class **extends** Applet"*  (emphasis mine)  I agree they are confused if trying to do this with applets, but they definitely seem to be using applets.

Comment: BTW - I'm itching to edit the OP's question to remove any reference to 'applet', but first I want to get them to come around to the idea that applets are not the tool for this job.